# Yii2 validate field as email if is not numeric

Tags: php, validation, yii2

i've this class in my project:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{

    public $fullname;
    public $info;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['fullname','info'],'required'
        ];
    }

}
```

I want to do a custom validation on my 'contact' field. I want to validate it as a mail if the value on the field isn't a number.

Is there a method for doing it with conditional validators?
Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do allot of things in order to accomplish this custom validator, play with input in beforeValidate() and such. Personally, the best way to do it is to set scenario. In your controller before you validate model check if user input is numeric with (is_numeric()), if it is set scenario to 'something1' if it's not then set scenario to 'mail'. This way you will not have to worry about validation because you will set two rules for the same attribute with different scenarios. One rule will be email other can be integerOnly or something like that. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an *inline* function to validate a field in your rules. In your case, i guess you might do something like:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['contact', 'validateContact'],
        ];
    }

    public function validateContact($attribute, $params)
    {
        if ( !is_numeric($this->$attribute) ) {
            $validator = new yii\validators\EmailValidator();
            if ($validator->validate($this->$attribute, $error)) {
                 echo 'Email is valid.';
            } else {
                 echo $error;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Contact is number';
        }
    }
```

More info:

1) http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

2) http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#using-client-side-validation